# What is the aggregate and intermediate in the artillery load test output

Tags: node.js, artillery

I am using the artillery.io load test for Node JS Rest API's. I am having single scenario with multiple flow in my json file. When I run the artillery test using run command and result having two objects as "aggregate" as object and "Intermediate" as array of objects. I am not able to find the meaning of that. Can anyone help me understand the difference.

Answer (score 2):

`intermediate` objects in the report correspond to the stats that are printed to the console as a test is running, which happens every 10 seconds by default (hence "intermediate"). The `aggregate` object is the stats for the entire duration of the test, which corresponds to the final stats printed to the console at the end of a test.